# can we reduce belly fat by machines or by medical treatments

Tags: bellyfat

I saw lot of companies advertising in online or in TV that we can reduce belly fat by using their machines. Is that really works , Is there any disadvantages  ?

[image]

Comment: No, you can't target fat loss.

Comment: @MJB Thanks , so means those machines are fake ?

Comment: Well the thing is, any type of exercise will burn calories, so yes if you use this machine it might get you some results (if you burn more calories than you consume on a daily basis). But the fact that you would get ripped abs or stuff like that from this specific machine is just marketing.

Comment: @MJB seems that will be an advantage for me..... I also want my abs to look attractive....

Comment: Getting your abs to look good is mostly related to diet. You already have a set of abs, they are just covered by a layer of fat at the moment. This type of exercise doesn't burn a lot of calories, doing heavy compound lifts (squats, deadlifts) or cardio (cycling, swimming) will burn a lot more calories and give you visible abs faster. Combine this with some ab work like leg raises or crunches and you will get great looking abs!

Comment: so you suggest workout in cardio , running and controlling diet is better than  using those machines ? also you can post your comment as answer......

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In short, **you can't target fat loss**, and what these types of companies are claiming is purely marketing. Sure, if you use a machine like this you will burn some calories, and if you burn more calories than you're consuming you will reduce fat (on your entire body) and get some results.

The thing is, **these types of machines aren't as effective at burning calories** as doing cardio (running, cycling, swimming) or doing heavy compound lifts (deadlifts, squats). They will burn a lot more calories, and combining this with some ab work like leg raises, crunches or planks will give you more results than these machines.

Also, **abs are revealed in the kitchen**, track your caloric intake and make sure you are burning more than you're consuming. And if you want to build some muscle, you have to make sure you get enough protein.

Comment: Point of clarification: Abs are *revealed* in the kitchen. Abs are made through doing exercise that works them, they are a muscle and respond in the same way to exercise stimulus. You won't get 'thick, defined' abs just eating less.

Comment: @JJosaur Obviously, I may have used the wrong word, but I explained the same thing (eating right and doing exercises that stimulate the core). I'll edit the word, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

There actually are a few medical things you do (beyond liposuction). Look into CoolScuplting and SculpSure. Both are FDA-approved. No experience with CoolScuplting, be we have a ScuplSure machine at our medi-spa, and I've seen it work firsthand. Up to a 25% reduction in fat for treated areas. Currently approved for abdomen, flanks, back and inner/outer thighs. Uses lasers to burn the fat away. Usually takes about 12 weeks to see full results.

That being said, for true body-recomposition, the comments and answers above hold true - abs are (mostly) made in the kitchen. Get into a calorie deficit, and stay there. I say mostly because without direct ab work, abs won't "pop" when you lose all the weight.